# Eigenvalues and basis of A power to 70

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi so I my assignment is to calculate the eigenvalues and basis of $A^{70}$, I've determined the values and basis for A and now I'm wondering how to proceed.
I've read that if $λ_1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $λ_1^k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$ so does that mean I should raise the eigenvalues I have to the power of 70, but how does that affect the basis?

Comment: Not at all. After all, we immediately find that $Av=\lambda v$ implies $A^kv=\lambda^kv$ (by induction). The only thing that can happen is that if $A$ does *not* have a basis of eigenvectors, then it may happen that $A^k$ does have one.

Comment: Consider $A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$.

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen Not sure I'm following you there

Comment: If applying $A$ to $v$ once just scales it by a factor of $\lambda$, then applying it twice just scales it by $\lambda$ twice.